# MongoDB Connection format and proper use in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB in my ASP.NET MVC web application on .NET Framework. My connection string format is like this:

```
mongodb+srv://projname:siyfdjfvhdsvf@projname.tag84.mongodb.net
```

The cluster is shared and free.

The problem is when I am using my connection string like this the crud operations are opening multiple connections and closed automatically some time after use.

How can I change this behavior to only use a single connection for all commands to the same collection?

I am having hard time understanding how to do it from the docs provided on mongodb site.

I have implemented repository pattern following [this](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/mongodb-repository-implementation-unit-testing-net-core-example/) its working but whenever a new request is send new connection is opening.
This is mainly affecting the concurrency request I have I tried singleton implementation following [this](https://weaseldotnet.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/mongodb-database-singleton-implementation/). But this is not working either.

My question is should I add some options in my connection string or use some other method ? What am I missing ?